# Users country name in silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I need to find users current country name with bing map api in silverlight4 application.
Can you please help me to achive this in silverlight application?

Comment: Can you use Html5 Geolocation API ? – If you already have the coordinates of the location that you want to reverse geocode, you can use the [CountryRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx) property in the API.

Comment: How can i use this in my application?

Comment: It's on Silverlight for WP ? Or just Silverlight ?

Comment: Its silverlight lync app

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is really what you want, but:

**1 - Write the JS code who return the position :**
[[Spec of geolocalisation api](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#get-current-position) | [Sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation)]

**2 - Call this method inside your Silverlight app :**
`HtmlPage.Window.Invoke` [Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.scriptobject.invoke%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

**3 - This method is async so callback your Silverlight app with JS :**
[Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293515/Calling-Silverlight-Method-from-Javascript-and-Jav)

**4 - Use [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx) or [GeocodeService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966793.aspx)** (`ReverseGeocodeRequest` contain an [Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966788.aspx) object with the country... ) **to reverse geocode the point.**

**Complete sample Step 1 -> 3 :** http://schumm.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/bing-maps-silverlight-plot-user-location/

Comment: It works with normal scenario. But it Fails when I connect to VPN. Its is unable to give me location. Just keeps loading; finally no result.

Comment: Add a `timeout` property as `getCurrentPosition` option and catch the timeout to stop loading process and show an error. In HTML5 Firefox use the Google Location Services with your IP and information about the nearby wireless access points. With VPN, IP is not located at the right place. You can try just with IP and service like [freegeoip](http://freegeoip.net/json/) but it's the same.

Comment: If an error occurs, you can offer the user to select his country? Perhaps by preselecting from its language information [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.95).aspx) and [RegionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo(v=vs.95).aspx)?

Comment: CultureInfo doesn't give me my exact location when I connect to VPN of other network which may be situated in Some other country than that of my current country.